# Select Sprite window has a delay after each letter I type as Unity filters sprites

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have dozens of sprites with the sprite mode Multiple in my game, which results in thousands of individual sprites once the sprites have been sliced.  When I click on the button in the Inspector to select a sprite for a Sprite Renderer, the Select Sprite dialog has a delay in it after every letter I type, presumably because Unity is filtering so many sprites.  Is there any way to get around this problem, such as making Unity only filter sprites when I type something and hit Enter (rather than filtering after each keystroke)?

Here's the window I'm talking about; there's a 1-2 second delay after each letter I type.

[image]

Comment: I think you can do it through the project folder and it will be easier

Comment: agree to bartek, organize your files and folders and use project folder